# React : filter json object with array of multiple possible values

Tags: json, reactjs, mapping, filtering

I have a json object
I imported it in the react component like this

```
import data from "../data/data.json";
```

This is my json object

```
{
"Cocktail": [
  {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "PL",
        "illustration": "img1",
        "ingredient": [{"percent": "1/10","ingredientname": "br"},
        {"percent": "4/10","ingredientname": "or"},
        {"percent": "5/10","ingredientname": "vo"}]
  },
...
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "AN",
    "illustration": "img3",
    "ingredient": [{"percent": "2/10","ingredientname": "br"},
     {"percent": "2/10","ingredientname": "li"},
     {"percent": "6/10","ingredientname": "ri"}
      ] 
    }
  ] 
}
```

I have this array

```
ingred = ["br", "or"]
```

I want to filter the json object file :
ingredientsname which have one of the corresponding value of ingred array and return the name of each element associated

I tried this

```
  return (
    <>
    {
    data.Cocktail
      .map((cocktail) => {
        return (
          <>
          {
           cocktail.ingredient.filter(ingredientcocktail => ingredientcocktail.ingredientname === ingred).map((ingredientcocktail) => {
                return (
                    <span key={cocktail.name}>
                    </span>
                );
              })
          }
          </> 
        );
      })
    }
  </>
  );
```

But it doesn't work : I don't know how to pass through items of the second array for the filtering.
Can someone could help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution :

```
data.Cocktails
  .map((cocktail) => {
    return (
      <>
      {
       cocktail.ingredient
        .filter(ingredientcocktail => ingred .includes(ingredientcocktail.ingredientname))
        .map((ingredientcocktail) => {
            return (
                <div key={ingredientcocktail.ingredientname}>
                  {cocktail.name}
                </div>
            );
          })
      }
      </> 
    );
  })
}
```

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, can't help you with ReactJs, but this should work in "plain" JS:

```js
let obj = {
    "Cocktail": [
      {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "PL",
            "illustration": "img1",
            "ingredient": [{"percent": "1/10","ingredientname": "br"},
            {"percent": "4/10","ingredientname": "or"},
            {"percent": "5/10","ingredientname": "vo"}]
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "AN",
        "illustration": "img3",
        "ingredient": [{"percent": "2/10","ingredientname": "br"},
         {"percent": "2/10","ingredientname": "li"},
         {"percent": "6/10","ingredientname": "ri"}
          ] 
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "asdasd",
          "illustration": "asdasd",
          "ingredient": [{"percent": "2/10","ingredientname": "asdasd"},
           {"percent": "2/10","ingredientname": "asdasd"},
           {"percent": "6/10","ingredientname": "asdasd"}
            ] 
          }
      ] 
    };
let wanted = ["br", "or"]
let res = obj.Cocktail.filter(
              el => el.ingredient.some( 
                   i => wanted.some(w => w == i.ingredientname)
              )
          ).map(cocktail => cocktail.name);
console.log(res)
```

(This is not meant to be "the most efficient way", so please, if you have more efficient way to do it, feel free to make an answer, and not complain about it on the comments)